# Using MahApps, how can we change MouseOver style of Expander's ToggleButton?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, expander

My WPF is using [MahApps metro](https://mahapps.com/) framework. As shown in figure 2 below, a mouseover on the header of any `Expander` control of the app makes the `ToggleButton` of the header almost invisible.

**Question**: How can we make this toggle button stand out more?

**XAML**:

```
<!-- ... -->
<Expander Header="Test expander" Width="145" Padding="0">
     <StackPanel>
          <Button Content="Button 1" Foreground="White"/>
          <Button Content="Button 2" Foreground="White"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Expander>
<!-- ... -->
```

**Display of the above Expander without mouseover on the Header**:

[image: Expander toggle button in normal state, the arrow and circle are white, the background is blue.]

**Display of the above Expander when mouseover on the Header**:

As you can see the `ToggleButton` on the left is almost invisible.

[image: Expander toggle button in mouse-over state, the arrow and circle are gray and hardly visible on the blue background.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 different styles for the `Expander` control, for up, down, left and right orientation. They all define the *Mouse Over* state the same way using [triggers in the repective control templates](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/78b523710dc4db1fd10392c2054f8923656ac436/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Expander.xaml#L156).

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray2}" />
        <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray2}" />
    </Trigger>
    <!-- ... -->
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

As you can see, the setters directly assign the `MahApps.Brushes.Gray2` using `DynamicResource`. They are not bound to any property or set in a style, so there are few options to change that, like:

- Create a custom style for [`MahApps.Styles.ToggleButton.ExpanderHeader.Down`](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/78b523710dc4db1fd10392c2054f8923656ac436/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Expander.xaml#L244) (and any diverse oriented `Expander` by copying the default style and adapting the *Mouse Over* trigger.
- Override the `MahApps.Brushes.Gray2` with a different brush or create a custom theme.

  ```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Gray2" Color="Black"/>
  ```

  You can override this brush in the application resource dictionary. However, this will impact not only the `Expander` control, but *all* controls that use this brush. If you redefine the brush in the `Expander` resources, it will apply to all of its children likewise.

Comment: I adapted your second option and it worked (thank you) as follows. Should it be good, or it may cause issues somewhere else? I have only one expander. Now the mouseover display is same as without mouseover (shown in image 1 of my post): `<Expander.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Gray2" Color="White"/>
</Expander.Resources>`

Comment: @nam Yes, it may cause issues. You have be aware, that the `MahApps.Brushes.Gray2` brush is used in more than one control and even in different styles that you might not know about. By overriding the brush, all controls and styles that use this brush and are in that scope (e.g. the children of the `Expander`) will apply it, which could lead to unwanted effects. Of course, you can test your application carefully, but the safer way is to create a custom style. However, there you might need to check and update your custom style with each new version of MahApps (default style might have changed).

Comment: Since, in my case, the scope of the brush is to a `specific` expander where (I have tested) it is not effecting its children, so I assume it should be ok (that is, the other controls outside this scope will not be effected). But your advice of using a custom style is worth taking a note of (in case I may need to use it for some other scenarios).